# Gulp: Object #<File> has no method 'isNull'

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-concat

I'm getting `TypeError: Object #<File> has no method 'isNull'` from both gulp-concat and gulp-sass:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    var dest = BUILD_DEST + 'scripts';
    del(dest);

    return gulp
        .src( scripts ) // scripts = [].concat(VENDOR_LIBS, APP_FILES)
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( concat('script.js') ) // everything is fine when this line is removed
                                     // Does the output file need to already exist?
        .pipe( gulp.dest( dest ) );
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    var dest = BUILD_DEST + 'styles';
    del(dest);

    return gulp
        .src( STYLE_FILES ) // STYLE_FILES = APP_SRC+'styles/*.scss'
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe(gulp.dest( dest ));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to accidentally using an old version of gulp (`3.0.0` vs `3.8.10`), which was incompatible with gulp-concat and gulp-sass. Upgrading to version `3.8.10` resolved the issue.

Comment: This is happening for me with `gulp-less`. Updated gulp versions and I'm still getting the error. Anyone know why?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that it didn't actually install a newer version? Try checking the version via CLI (probably `gulp --version`).

Comment: Still getting this issue with `"gulp": "^3.9.0", "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0"` sadly

Comment: Did you check the version of gulp that's actually being used (via `gulp --version`) ?